# Is it necessary to create provisioning profile from paid developer account to test app in real device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa

Paid developer account in one mac and xcode in other mac.. so can i test app in real device connect iphone with USB to mac with normal apple account.

if i cant test app with normal apple developer account(without paid apple developer account) then what i need to create from paid developer account for test app in real device and to create IPA file..

can i create provisioning profile in one mac and that profile can i install in xcode which is in other mac.

Please help me in the above three questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on your questions, but I think you want to share your app with your friend / client to test with normal account.

If this is the query, **you can do that**.

Follow this link and make IPA file.

[https://medium.com/mλgnξtλr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3](https://medium.com/m%CE%BBgn%CE%BEt%CE%BBr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3)

After that you can install that by using cydiaimpector on any PC/Laptop

Comment: Yes you can test by attaching USB cable to iPhone

Comment: Just one query.. i have paid acc in one mac and xcode with app in other mac so can i create provisioning profile in paid acc and install in xcode which is in other account

Comment: No, provisioning profiles are linked with the account. Even if you get all the certificates from one mac to another mac, you have to have a login in every mac - in Xcode.

Comment: okay, thank u, defnetly i'll accept and upvote for sure..my last question.. for testing means in development for generating IPA file what we need to create in paid apple . developer account to install in xcode signing

Comment: for creating IPA file and test app in real device what i need to create in paid apple developer accont..like certificate, id , device to be registered in apple account and provisioning profile.... or anything else

Comment: First of all you have to register your device with your account. Then create developing certificate now create provisioning profile by selecting your newly created certificate and device you just added. Install both of them ( certificate, provisioning profile) in your mac and login with your account in xcode, now you can do testing with that device.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to pay 99$ just for testing/running your app in your device via USB. This blog gives step by step detailed and updated flow of installing development apps on real iOS devices for testing purpose.
Have a [look](https://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/).
Hope it helps. Thanks